# Infinite Addition Loop

Tags: vb.net, plc

I basically have 4 tags that keep a count of product produced within the company. The problem is that the logic behind these tags is to reset the value when the machine stops. I am not too familiar with coding, but am trying to develop a calculation tag that will just keep a running count without reset. So basically, the number would always escalate.

Tag Names : Filler1Count , Filler2Count, Filler3Count, Filler4Count

This is all done in an application called Historian Administrator. VB code can be implemented behind tags. I will obviously be keeping the original tags, but have the option of making a calculation tag.

Comment: so, what is the problem here?

Comment: This is very unclear. I would suggest you read up on [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) which would allow you to store a large amount of numbers.

Comment: The problem is that the number is reset. I would to provide a calculation that will add all the previous retrieved values. I said that in the post.

Comment: This is an HMI application, right? Care to specify the platform and add a bit more detail?

Comment: Yes. Proficy Historian Administrator. The tags are linked to IGS, which is then linked to PLC logic.

Comment: Oh god! I could help you out with a lot of packages but GE isn't something I've ever used. Sorry.

Comment: Just a thought, wouldn't it be easier to add a totaliser for each value in the PLC instead and just point the historian at that?

Answer (score 0):

Watch for when the number is smaller than the previous poll and store your total in a different variable.

```
If Filler1Count < LastFiller1Count Then
    Filler1Total = Filler1Total + LastFiller1Count
End If
LastFiller1Count = Filler1Count
Total = Filler1Total + Filler1Count
```